# How to modify .htaccess file in order to redirect some html pages if they don't exists?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect all the .html file like this:

www.sitename.com/art/5.html

to the following (equivalent) php page:

www.sitename.com?art=5

but ONLY if the .html file doesn't exist, otherwise it should not redirect. What should I write in my .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
# Test if the file exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# And redirect if not
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)\.html$ /?$1=$2 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `untested` should work

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)\.html$ /?$1=$2 [L,R=301]
```